# Erroring AWS SSM via command line

Tags: aws-ssm

aws ssm send-command --document-name "nessus_uninstallation_linux_ubuntu" --document-version "1" --targets '[{"Key":"InstanceIds","Values":["i-0114639d5f5f21chgfhgbd"]}]' --parameters '{"Message":["Bye bye Nessus!"]}' --timeout-seconds 600 --max-concurrency "50" --max-errors "0" --output-s3-bucket-name "cybersecurity" --output-s3-key-prefix "ssm-logs" --cloud-watch-output-config '{"CloudWatchOutputEnabled":true,"CloudWatchLogGroupName":"/aws-ssm/ssm-logs"}' --region us-east-2

An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation: Instances [[i-0114639d5f5f21chgfhgbd]] not in a valid state for account 3435456546467